# Shopify Plus script to detect product tags

Tags: shopify

I have Shopify Plus store and I want to apply script using Ruby in checkout for shipping method.

Here how I want it

If a product tagged with XXX is in cart show only YYY (by name) Shipping Option and show this message "ZZZ".

Comment: Hi @WebContrive, welcome to SO! Please take the tour and check the help pages about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question does not show any effort and people are not likely to do the job for you. Good luck!

Comment: A Quick Suggestion! Hire an expert Shopify script developer, and relieve yourself of this question as a problem in your store!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're after is the Shopify Script Editor: https://apps.shopify.com/script-editor

This is only available for Shopify Plus clients (which you are), and it allows you to customize a few aspects of the checkout - including the ability to manipulate which shipping methods are available to a customer.

Once you've installed the Script Editor app, you can add your custom behaviours to your checkout.  For help on how to do this, see the documentation at https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor

For an example of how to remove shipping methods specifically, see also: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/examples#remove-a-shipping-rate

You can get product tags in a shipping script the same way you would in a line-item script:

```
Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item| 
  product = line_item.variant.product 
  if product.tags.include? 'my-tag' 
    [stuff]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes i got that but how can i get Cart product's Tags ?

Comment: By looping through the cart's line items, same way you would in a product-discount script. ``` Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
  product = line_item.variant.product
  if product.tags.include? 'my-tag'
  [stuff]```

Comment: Hm... That formatting doesn't seem to work in comments. Ammending answer.